# AWGN BER simulation on MATLAB/Simulink does not generate the same theoretical results

Tags: matlab, simulink

The Simulink simulation is shown below:

[image]

I am attempting a simulation of a very simple system using BPSK at a rate of 10 MHz. However, I am not sure about the AWGN block values. Specifically,

1. On "Signal to Noise Ratio (Eb/No)", what is the "Input signal power, referenced to 1 ohm (watts)" parameter?. How can I calculate this value? When I use the default value, which is 1, I get the following curve:
   [image]
2. Alternatively, when I am simulating using the "Variance from Mask" option and variance = 10^(-EbNo/10), I get the following result:

[image]

Clearly, they theoretical and simulated curves are not overlapping. For this plot, I am using the Monte Carlo option found in BERTool.

Answer (score 0):

Two observations:

1. The signal power at the input of the AWGN has to be normalized to one in order to the parameter of the AWGN module to one
2. The receive square raised cosine has a parameter called "decimation offset". This is used for taking the perfect sampling instant.